# How to check for NaN in golang

Tags: go, nan

How can I check whether a float variable is NaN or not? e.g.

```
math.Log(1.0) // not NaN
math.Log(-1.0)  // NaN
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use `math.IsNaN(...)` for that: [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/edvbSR-Cth)

Comment: A noteworthy addendum while we're on it: `math.NaN()` is not equal to itself: https://play.golang.org/p/H_SziEAdCvc

Comment: NaN == NaN results to false in every language as per the IEEE 754 spec which nearly all languages implement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Answer (score 17):

Use [`math.IsNaN`](http://golang.org/pkg/math/#IsNaN):

> IsNaN reports whether f is an IEEE 754 “not-a-number” value.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in Nico's comment, because NaN is defined as `f != f`, that's all that `math.IsNaN` does.
[See the src here](https://golang.org/src/math/bits.go?s=791:822#L24).

So, you can just check:

```
if f != f {
    fmt.Printf("%v is NaN", f)
}
```

Edited to make into a standalone answer.